# How to stop my child's teacher from disciplining my child without my consent?

Tags: discipline, teacher

My daughter is 6 she is diagnosed add adhd fetal exposure. We adopted her at 6 weeks. I told the school after a assistant teacher terrorized my child into saying she was lying when she wasn’t not to discipline my child with out my knowledge or permission. My daughter was sent to detention and I was not informed or notified. My daughter came home and told me. My daughter isn’t perfect but, last year she was a beautiful engaged child. The teacher loved working with her. This year my child’s teacher doesn’t respond to written request. I’ve actually had to involve the superintendent office. I want my baby to have a great education experience but, I’m really getting over it with this teacher.

What can I do to stop my child's teacher from disciplining my child without my consent?

Comment: Is changing schools viable?

Answer (score 5):

It can be so painful to see your child suffer at the hands of school staff.

Are you in the U.S.?  There is a list of regional parent centers which have training programs that help parents advocate for their child, and which offer one on one support at no cost: https://www.parentcenterhub.org/find-your-center/

Also you may want to get involved with the Council of Parent Attorneys and Advocates (COPAA, copaa.org) through peer support, and training.

Depending on where you live, you might be able to find a parent advocate who can attend school meetings with you.  Some advocates charge for their services, some don't.  You could also trade off with another parent -- attending each other's meetings and taking notes.

Understood.org is a good resource for learning more about your rights and your daughter's rights under IDEA and Section 504.

Also parents in your situation often find it helpful to keep a log about what your child is experiencing at school, and what staff and administrators are telling you (verbally and in writing with letters and emails).